# jquery dialog widget does not preserve parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Here's a very simple script to illustrate my point. I'd like to think i'm just doing something wrong.
http://jsfiddle.net/9qx2q/2/

the HTML

```
<form id='myForm'>
    <div class="panelClass"> 
        Here's my jquery panel
    </div>
</form>
```

and for the script

```
//when the div is dialog'ed it's relocated to be a child of body?
$('.panelClass').dialog({
    //appendTo : '#myForm', // uncomment to see that this does not move the panel
    create : function(e, ui) {
        //$(this).dialog('widget').appendTo('#myForm'); //uncomment to see that this DOES move the panel
    }
});
```

the output

```
<body>
  <form id="myForm"></form>
  <div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-

resizable" style="outline: 0px; z-index: 1003; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 300px; top: 235px; left: 104px; display: block;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">&nbsp;</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a></div><div class="panelClass ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 82px; height: auto;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0"> 
            Here's my jquery panel
        </div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 1000;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 1000;"></div></div>
</body>
```

You'll see from the above example that the form element is now empty with the panel having been created after the form. When .dialog() is called on the panel, the panel is moved to the end of `<body>`.

Basically the situation is this.
I have a panel within a form. This panel needs to be within the form as when it pops up, it will have input elements that need to be maitained on the form. (sometimes we pop these panels to get users to submit more info, etc).

While i do have a working solution, i.e. by updating the create method, i really don't think this should be moving elements around in the first place.... Unless... i'm just doing something wrong.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs `appendTo` will be added on jQuery UI 1.10.0 http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo

What you are facing, is a default behavior of jQuery UI dialog, it attach the dialogs at the end of the body http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7948, so I don't think is a problem of your code.

For now the only workaround is what are you doing now on `create` or `open` events.

### EDIT

If you want you can take a look at this my answer too: [Append jQuery UI dialog to its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264201/append-jquery-ui-dialog-to-its-parent/16118392#16118392)

Comment: GAH! can't believe i missed that comment in the docs. Well that explains why it doesn't work for me. Judging by that ticket it seems they were initially very reluctant to add this.

Comment: @Beta033 Added a link to a similar answer with a possible workaround

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using HTML5, you can set the `form` attribute to associate an `<input>` with a form without having the element within a `<form>` tag:

```
<input type="text" form="myForm">
```

Comment: I suppose that could work in a vacuum, but with the number of panels we have around the system, changing this individually or through a jquery selector would be impractica. besides, it feels wrong to hack to all my image buttons to get around something that jquery should not be doing anyway, i.e moving elements on the page.